# How to export a constructor from privileged scope to a less-privileged scope in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, web-audio-api

I'm trying to write a Firefox extension which hooks into WebAudio and adds a 'master-gain' to all AudioContexts.

I am trying to do this by overriding the AudioContext constructor in the `window` namespace. This way I can return a GainNode (which is internally connected to the `destination`) when the user tries to access `destination`. It's a hack, but I think it might be useful.

I'm currently struggling at exporting my `newAudioContext` constructor from the addon script(privileged scope) into the page script (less-privileged).

I tried...

`unsafeWindow.AudioContext = cloneInto(newAudioContext,unsafeWindow);`

But I still get the original AudioContext in the page script.

I also tried

`exportFunction(newAudioContext, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "AudioContext"});`

but that exports it as a function and not as a constructor.

I understand that structured cloning has limitations, but are there any other ways I can override the window.AudioContext from an AddOn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run more complex code (e.g. object construction) in the unprivileged context you can simply import a script into the target window (after waiving xrays) through the [mozIJSSubScriptLoader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader).
Any function that needs to call into privileged code can be patched into its prototype from the chrome side after the script has been loaded.

You can do this before DOM parsing - and thus before any content script execution - by listening to the [DOMWindowCreated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMWindowCreated) event.

You will have to do this from a [frame script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager#Loading_frame_scripts), since the addon-sdk's page-mod sandboxes don't have enough privileges to access the script loader.

Keeping interaction with the unsafe window to a minimum, i.e. either running code wholly in the privileged environment with [xrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision) or completely in the untrusted environment with the minimal amount of glue methods between those two seems like good security hygiene anyway.

Of course you should be aware that content code will be able to pick apart and modify any classes you create in content. It is untrusted after all.

Comment: Cool! This sounds like something that may work. Let me try it out.

Comment: OK. I'm a little confused. I should be calling `mozIJSSubScriptLoader` from my addon code right? I'm using the addon SDK so this would in inside my `main.js` code? Sorry I'm really new to making addons.

Comment: Furthermore how can I make the `window` of the webpage that's loaded the `targetObj` for the `mozIJSSubScriptLoader` ?